# Automate associating to ssid on windows based on bssid

Tags: wireless-networking, ieee802.1x

Trying to automate wifi association to an ssid based on bssid (split ssid not possible) .

Initially I used netsh and xml to associate.

```
    <MSM>
        <security>
            <authEncryption>
                <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>
                <encryption>AES</encryption>
                <useOneX>false</useOneX>
            </authEncryption>
            <sharedKey>
                <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
                <protected>false</protected>
                <keyMaterial>xxxxxxxx</keyMaterial>
            </sharedKey>
        </security>
     </MSM>
</WLANProfile>
```

In this case my client is sending a probe req, probe rsp auth eapol etc.

Unfortunately Windows netsh utility is not natively supporting bssid option.

So i switched over to python importing pywifi and the the desired tool. The script at the end indicates that the device is connected to my bssid, but no action is happening. I noticed on OTA sniff i my client in this instance is unable to send authentication req. to the gateway. Also there isn't an option for aes encrytion.

```
wifi = pywifi.PyWiFi()
        iface = wifi.interfaces()[0]
        
        profile = pywifi.Profile()
        print(pywifi.Profile())
        profile.ssid = desired_ssid
        profile.auth = const.AUTH_ALG_OPEN
        profile.akm.append(const.AKM_TYPE_WPA2PSK)
        profile.cipher = const.CIPHER_TYPE_CCMP
        profile.key = "xxxxxxxxxx"  # Replace with your WiFi password
        profile.bssid = desired_bssid   # Set the desired BSSID
        iface.remove_all_network_profiles()  # Remove previous profiles
        iface.connect(profile)
```

This is a windows 11 machine with intel ac 8265 chip on it.